# Django loaddata - instance is on database "postgres", value is on database "default"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-database

I need to migrate from `sqlite3` to `postgres`. The `dumpdata` of the whole database doesn't work so I'm doing it one by one. The problem is that when I try to load `users` it raises error:

```
ValueError: Problem installing fixture '/.../dbmig/auth.user.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): Cannot add "<Group: contractor>": instance is on database "postgres", value is on database "default"
```

This is not true, because the `groups` were migrated before users.

I've created a command that I use:

```
def dumpload(model):
    json_filename = model+'.json'

    DBMIG_DIR = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'dbmig')
    json_filepath = os.path.join(DBMIG_DIR,json_filename)

    with open(json_filepath, 'w') as f:
        call_command('dumpdata', model, stdout=f, database='default')

    call_command('loaddata', json_filepath, database='postgres')

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        dumpload('auth.group')
        dumpload('auth.user')
```

**EDIT**

It doesn't make sense, the groups are already in the `postgres` db. I've added `print(Group.objects.using('postgres').values('pk'))` between the two commands and I can clearly see that the groups are in the `postgres` database and they have correct ids.

This is the output:

```
Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
<QuerySet [{'pk': 1}, {'pk': 2}]>
error...
```

**EDIT - settings.DATABASES**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
        },
        'NAME': config.get('db', 'name'),
        'USER': config.get('db', 'user'),
        'PASSWORD': config.get('db', 'password'),
        'HOST': config.get('db', 'host'),
        'PORT': config.get('db', 'port'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your `DATABASES` setting.

Comment: @schillingt Ok, I've added the DATABASES setting to the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: Can you make the postgres database the `default` and use the other name for the `sqlite`? I think there may be a bug in `loaddata` when using multiple databases. You'll have to look through the django tickets to find out for sure though.

Comment: @schillingt Yes, this approach works. Thank you. It's probably a bug.